# iphone, localization, info.plist

Tags: iphone, localization, itunes

If I declare "Japanese, French, German, Simplified Chinese, Thai" in the "Localization" field of my app's myApp-info.plist file, will the iTunes Store detect this and correctly advertise these (together with the "Localization native development region" of "English") as the languages in which my app is available?

If not, what should I do to make sure these localizations are advertised?

Should I replace the "Localization" entry with comma-separated string of ISO_639-1 codes "en, fr, de, ja, th, zh-Hans"?

Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your Info.plist, you need a "Localizations" (CFBundleLocalizations is the raw key name) entry of array type. Add all the supported languages to the array as separated items of the form "English", "German", etc. You don't need to use ISO codes.

On iTunes Connect, you will also want to localize the description of your app when you do the submission.

Comment: Check - Are you saying this from experience? The only way I have of being sure is submitting the app in the first place?

Comment: Yes, I've submitted quite a few apps already. Again I recommend you add localized descriptions on iTunes Connect (even if you just copy-past the English texts). You never know when Apple will change their policies…

Comment: Thanks! The localized descriptions aren't the problem -- they're already there. I was trying to understand why the localizations are not advertised (only English is) and it looks like using ISO codes here is a mistake...

Comment: @Julio: Your answer is just the ticket. But more it is an error to use the ISO codes to advertise localizations in the info.plist file. These won't be displayed on the iTunes page, more than likely only English will be advertised.

Comment: Am I the only who can't add the "Localizations" key as an array. By default it adds it as a string, and when you enter say French, it adds in fact 'fr'. Any clue on that?

Comment: You need to right click on the Key (Localizations), then set Value Type to Array. Please upvote my answer if this helped :)

Comment: The only way I can do this, is by opening in source code mode. Not with Plist GUI. But that's fine. I also found this: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-109552 you can use ISO codes too.

Answer (score 9):

At the end of the document [iOS User Experience - Internationalization Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/LanguageDesignations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002144) it says that the words English, French, Portuguese,... are now deprecated and their ISO codes should be used instead.

(I wanted to add this as a comment to the most voted post, and that's why I registered in the first place, but apparently I don't have enough reputation to do so yet. Oh! And thank you, Julio, your answer helped me a lot. ;) )